# Will GIN index be used with sql ANY operator in PostgreSql

Tags: arrays, postgresql, indexing

I'm wondering if PostgreSql will use `GIN` index for `ANY` operator with an integer array. Lets say I have a table `tree_nodes` which contains `id` with type `int` and `path` with type `int[]`. Simple example:

[image]

Will GIN index be used when I wrote a select `select * from tree_nodes where :id = any(path)` and, for example `:id` = 2.

I know, that [in case of @>](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) it will, but I believe, that in my case `ANY` operator will be more effective than `@>`

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GIN index cannot be used with `=ANY`.

What you can do is to use the `<@` operator with a one-element array:

```
SELECT * FROM tree_nodes
WHERE ARRAY[$1] <@ path;
```

Here the GIN index can be used.

Comment: Thank you. Really, there is no need to use `ANY` here